# Suppressing sh script output when using <<END

Tags: shell, output, sh, suppress

I want to insert commands into an interactive environment using the following method:

```
bc <<END
1+1
quit
END
```

The output of the example is '`2`' and it appears after typing `END`. Suppose I would want to suppress this output. So after typing END I don't want any output to appear. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish it redirecting the output of `bc` to `/dev/null`:

```
$ bc &>/dev/null <<END
1+1
quit
END
```

Note that using `& > /dev/null` both stdout and stderr will be sent to `/dev/null`, so not output will appear at all.

Comment: Thanks, this works. My mistake was that I tried putting > /dev/null after the END. I will accept your answer.

Comment: To be honest, my first attempt was also like that :)